# Extracting and formatting date string to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm scraping a string from a website where I would like to save the first date to a MySQL database.

How can I extract the below first date in the correct format to add it to a MySQL database?

```
Mar 31, 2015, 7:45pm CT | Last updated Mar 31, 2015, 7:49pm CT
```

doing dynamically

```
$daily_date = $sum_html->find("//div[@id='dd-article-dates']/time/string()", 0);



$daily_date_format = DateTime::createFromFormat('M d, Y, g:ia e', explode('|', $daily_date)[0]);


$daily_date_mysql = $daily_date_format->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $daily_date_mysql;
```

Comment: You want to change `Mar 31, 2015` to `03/31/2015 ` ?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried and what happened?

Comment: I want to extract Mar 31, 2015, 7:45pm and add it to a mysql database

Comment: Where is your php code for your inserting operation ?

Comment: Timezone matter? You could explode on pipe then grab the first result and format it to MySQL's expected format

Comment: yes would be best with 24 hour clock

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's multiple ways to do this. I used `explode()` to get the part of the string we wanted to work with and then `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to parse it into a `DateTime()` object. Formatting it from there is easy..

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('M d, Y, g:ia ??', explode(' | ', 'Mar 31, 2015, 7:45pm CT | Last updated Mar 31, 2015, 7:49pm CT')[0]);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/310721)

Comment: It seems, the questioner wants to save it in db

Comment: I just conveyed you. `I am not asking you to provide him with code` Can you see the comments below the question.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in /tmp/execpad-39197b8b7ced/source-39197b8b7ced on line 6

in your demo

Comment: The date format is probably not consistent. Post the date you used that through that error so I can update the code accordingly.

Comment: The date can either just be "Feb 26, 2015, 6:52pm CT" or "Mar 31, 2015, 7:45pm CT | Last updated Mar 31, 2015, 7:49pm CT" depending if it has been updated

Comment: I've added in the question what i'm doing at the moment where $daily_date is the scraped string

Comment: Could the reason why my dynamic dates not working cause there is a lot of whitespace before and after like "           Mar 24, 2015, 9:36pm CT          "?

Comment: Yes. if your `trim()` those values that should resolve that issue.